# ngrepeat changing entire array is slow

Tags: angularjs, performance, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to replace the contents of the array backing my ng-repeat (performing a search query and updating a list), and I've noticed the performance is really slow to update. In trying to troubleshoot this I've discovered `track by`, but using it still doesn't address the issue.

What I'm seeing:

1. start with a ng-repeat containing 25 or so items (images)
2. get a new list of data by querying the server (a few ms)
3. update the array, setting it equal to an array containing the new contents (a few ms)
4. (several hundred ms go by) the page updates

Things I've tried without success:

1. try using `track by`

   - if any items were already in the list, the update of just those items is **fast**, but I still have to wait a few hundred ms for the rest to update
2. update the list and immediately trigger a `$scope.$apply()` call

   - no effect since it already started the digest cycle
3. set an empty array first, `$scope.$apply()`, then set the new list

   - same slow update

The initial rendering of the list is very quick, it's just a slow operation to change the entire list even if I'm replacing it with a single element. I know I'm not the first to encounter this, but I can't find the right google incantation that gets me around all of the `track by` answers so I can address this.

Comment: To isolate the problem: what happens if you strip the markup of the ng-repeat (preferable on a clean page) and just do something like `<div ng-repeat="item in items">{{ item.name }}</div>`? AFAIK the `track by` is optional; if none is specified it will be tracked by the object itself.

Comment: Same issue, but it led me to the actual problem! I have an animation that quickly staggers the opacity for each image (at .015s delay for each succeeding image). By turning this off, the update is now nearly instantaneous. I'll have to now play around with the animation to figure out how to address the problem. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Hi, Did you ever find solution for this. I have same exact problem.